# XMLHttpRequest in IE 8-9 with header

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, xmlhttprequest, internet-explorer-9

Is there way to make GET request with headers in IE 8-9? 
I readed about XDomainRequest, but it don't support headers. I can't use jQuery on my project and have to do it using only JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add custom headers to the XDR object. See this blog post for more information: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx